# When coding in java, is the main Data type that is used called int?

Tags: java, integer, double

During my course, my professor said to only use int, and double in Java. The text book I am reading goes over byte, int, short, double, long, and float. I understand that each of these handle a different amount of data.

My question is, is int primarily used for programming? and if so, do I only practice using int and double? and if not, do I try to use all the above?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Int is the most used of the integer types; double is the best of the floating point types for most uses. When extreme precision is needed, there is BigDecimal, but you can leave this for later.

Comment: Java is Object Oriented language. While it supports primitives like `int`, `double`, `char`, etc. it's main power is in dealing with rather complex objects.

Comment: If you want to handle integer values over about 2 billion with complete precision then `int` will not be large enough and `double` will not be precise enough. So no, those 2 by themselves are not sufficient for every problem.

Comment: Each data type has its own purpose. Your professor is probably trying to get you to start off with just two type to keep things simple until you understand the basics. I would keep reading the text book though.I think it's better to learn about all the basic data types from the start.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a pretty vanilla answer.

By *default*, a literal number in Java is interpreted as an `int`.  For instance, `123` is always going to be an `int`.

By *default*, a floating-point decimal number in Java is interpreted as a `double`.  For instance, `123.45` is always going to be a `double`.

You can add `L` to the end of a number to create a `long`, or `f` at the end of a decimal number to create a `float`.

There are a myriad of other numeral containers that can do numbers higher than the limits of either a 32 or a 64-bit signed number, or that can hold more precision than a 64-bit double (such as `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`), so the *correct* answer to if it's primarily used is that **it really depends on what it is you're doing**.

Java has its defaults, but you don't have to stick to them.